# MAX() Function in sql returns only first character of digit

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using code like this

```
$query = "SELECT Max(Vote) FROM VoteTab"; 
$result = mysqli_query($this->link,$query);
$query_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

foreach ($query_data as $record){
    $VoteCount=$record['Vote'];
    echo $VoteCount;
}
```

It returns value 5, but actual value is 56. If the value is 67 then it returns only 6. But it works fine for me in my localhost.

```
Id    Vote Name
1      23  Rohan
2      56  Vivek
3      32  Rahul
4      78  Broh
5      0   Tack
6      0   grey
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your table in sqlfiddle ?

Comment: What if you alias `Max(Vote) AS maxVote` and do `$VoteCount = @record['maxVote'];`?

Comment: @Uueerdo Wouldn't it be `$VoteCount = @$record['maxVote'];`...maybe a typo of missing `$` sign

Comment: can you post your table structure ?

Comment: @RakibulIslam going by his current code it'd just be `$VoteCount = $record['maxVote'];` that was just a typo on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` gets you one row of the result, which you then iterate with `foreach`, which is wrong. Correct code should be:

```
$query = "SELECT Max(Vote) FROM VoteTab"; 
$result = mysqli_query($this->link,$query);
$query_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $query_data['Max(Vote)'];
```

Comment: It returns value answer like this   78tackgrey

Comment: Single call to code mentioned above may only return one value. So you have something else in your code, that outputs strings _Tack_ and _grey_.

Answer (score 0):

**You can update just on query** :

```
$query = "SELECT Vote FROM VoteTab order by Vote desc limit 1"; 

$result = mysqli_query($this->link,$query);

$query_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


foreach ($query_data as $record){

    $VoteCount=$record['Vote'];

    echo $VoteCount;

         }
```